Which option is better for showing proof of funds for Canada visitor visa application?
I'm a married individual living with my wife and mother in India. I'm intending to visit my sister in Canada and therefore need to apply for a visitor visa. Here's my situation:
I'm a salaried employee, but due to various investments offered by my employer such as the Employee Stock Purchase Program and Employee Provident Fund, my in-hand salary appears relatively low. Moreover, I have an ongoing home loan, with the monthly EMI consuming 60% of the funds credited to my salary account. Consequently, my six-month bank statement might not be sufficient as proof of funds.
I'm contemplating two possible options to bolster my visa application:

Liquidating some of my stocks and transferring the funds into my savings account. I would then explain in my cover letter that these funds genuinely belong to me and provide transaction details to support this assertion.

Showing my diverse portfolio of investments, which includes mutual funds, stocks, bonds, and joint property, as proof of funds.


In both cases, I plan to provide supporting documents such as an Employer No Objection Certificate (NOC) and pay stubs.
Which of these options would be more favorable for my Canada visitor visa application?


What proportion of your in-hand salary are you spending in a typical month? How much is left over each month after expenses? 2) Where were you planning on getting the cash to pay for your trip? Were you going to liquidate stacks? Something else?


In a typical month, I spend 80% of my in-hand salary. I plan to sell some stocks + mutual funds (<5% of investments) to fund my trip.

Immigration officers are looking for two things:

Do you actually have enough money to pay for the visit you are making?
Does it actually make financial sense for you to be spending this amount on a trip right now?

As an example of the second, if you were not earning less enough to cover rent and other expenses it would not make sense for you to be taking a trip. They would suspect that you were looking for get a job in the country.
Your case seems to be OK. Spending 80 of income is fairly normal, especially if you are "saving " in other ways. I would include your payslips in your submission and note the deductions that could be considered "saving".
Since you are going to liquidate stocks to pay for the trip I would go ahead and do that before the application. Include evidence of where the funds came from. Including a statement of your investments would also be a good idea - showing that you are not using all your funds on this trip.

The requirement is to have enough money for your stay depending on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
The assets in your portfolio help to demonstrate your overall financial situation but eg a joint share in a property is illiquid and isn’t going to let you pay your trip costs right now. So IMHO option 1 is better.
